# Замена ссылок с кириллицы на латиницу

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Привет! На сайте на Wordpress выводились ссылки в кириллице, поменял их с помощью плагина "Cyr to Lat enhanced", но в самих постах и страницах остались ссылки в кириллице. Есть ли возможность эти ссылки тоже как-то исправить?

Comment: исопльзуйте плагин Cyr AND LAt - он намного лучше

Comment: и обнови пермалинки